# Send buffer as a download file to user

Tags: node.js

I am trying to send a MS Excel buffer (built by JSZIP) as a download file to the client. Here's my code.

```
var fileBuffer;

workbook.generate(function(err, jszip) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        fileBuffer = jszip.generate({type: "nodebuffer"});
    }
});

res.send(workbookBuffer);
}
```

since this is being called by a Service from the Client side;

```
ReportsService.fetch(values).then(function(response) {                    
    }, function(err){
        console.err(err);
    });
```

I get the buffer in response in the method above (which lies in the client.controller). I would like to have this behave as a file download to the user.

Comment: Behaving like a file download, means the user has to click something etc. you can't randomly download files to the client. Add a link, and make the route return the correct headers for a file download

Comment: The user would click the download button and using msexcel-builder, an excel workbook is created and later transformed into a buffer (nodebuffer), I'm looking for a way to throw that buffer to the client as a file to download, any leads?